# Multi-Platform SQL Query Validator

Tags: sql, validation

Does anyone know of a tool that can verify that a given SQL statement is valid across different databases (oracle, db2, mssql)?

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I think you're best bet here is going to be to write your own simple test harness that connects to the various test databases (I'm presuming that you have a database of each flavour in order to test against), executes your statement and validates the response. In this respect it would also act as a means to unit test all of your database code. I reckon you could knock something together in your language of choice in about 20 minutes, which is probably why there's not already a tool to do this.